# Plotting Celery canvas before running

Tags: python, graph, celery, graphviz

There is documentation on [how to produce a graph after running a canvas job](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#graphs) in Celery.
However I'd like to generate a graph *before* I run the job.

Say I created a simple chain:

```
c = chain(add.s(1, 2), mul(4))
```

How can I generate a graph of the chain?

### Thanks,

Miki

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same desire. Generate the graph before running the job. So I worked a bit on it :)

It appears that celery does not allow it. The reason for that (at least what I understood when trying to do it) is that in the graph each node has to have a unique name. Once the canvas is executed this unique name is the celery task_id but before execution there is nothing that allow such a distinction.

So the solution is to generate this graph by yourself, and of course identify uniquely each node (for this a counter can do the work).

This is the job of this function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery.canvas import chain, group, Signature


def analyze_canvas(canvas):
    return _analyze_canvas(canvas)['dependencies']


def _analyze_canvas(canvas, previous=[], i=0):
    dependencies = []

    if isinstance(canvas, chain):
        for t in canvas.tasks:
            if not (isinstance(t, group) or isinstance(t, chain)):
                n = str(t) + " - (" + str(i) + ")"
                i += 1
                dependencies.append((n, previous))
                previous = [n]
            else:
                analysis = _analyze_canvas(t, previous, i)
                dependencies.extend(analysis['dependencies'])
                previous = analysis['previous']
    elif isinstance(canvas, group):
        new_previous = []
        for t in canvas.tasks:
            if not (isinstance(t, group) or isinstance(t, chain)):
                n = str(t) + " - (" + str(i) + ")"
                i += 1
                dependencies.append((n, previous))
                new_previous.append(n)
            else:
                analysis = _analyze_canvas(t, previous, i)
                dependencies.extend(analysis['dependencies'])
                new_previous = analysis['previous']
        previous = new_previous
    elif isinstance(canvas, Signature):
        n = str(t) + " - (" + str(i) + ")"
        i += 1
        dependencies.append((n, previous))
        previous = [n]
    return {"dependencies": dependencies,
            "previous": previous}
```

It generates the dependency graph of your canvas. The idea is just to iterate other the tasks of the canvas and identify group/chain/Signatures to generate the right dependencies.

From this point you can use some more celery utils to generate the dot file. Here is a small usage example:

```
from celery_util import analyze_canvas
from celery.datastructures import DependencyGraph
from celery import Celery, group

app = Celery()

@app.task
def t1():
    pass

@app.task
def t2():
    pass

canvas = t1.si() | t2.si() | group(t1.si(), t1.si(), t2.si()) | t2.si()

d = analyze_canvas(canvas)
dg = DependencyGraph(it=d)
pipo = open("pipo.dot", "w+")
dg.to_dot(pipo)
```

In this example I just declare dummy tasks and chain/group them in a nice pretty canvas. I use the celery util `DependencyGraph` to have the object representation and the ability to dump the graph in dot which I do with `to_dot` method.

And the beautiful result is:
[image: Task graph]

Comment: Could you please update this snippet to Celery 4? Thanks

Comment: Working on it but it's not that easy :)

Comment: In Celery 4, `signature.freeze()` can be used to get an `AsyncResult` _before_ executing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105701/928489 to work with celery4. It works with chain, group and chord.

```
from app.instant_design import get_instant_design_tasks
from celery.canvas import _chain, group, chord


def analyze_canvas(canvas):
    return _analyze_canvas(canvas)[0]


def _analyze_canvas(canvas, previous=[], i=0):
    dependencies = []

    if isinstance(canvas, _chain):
        for i, t in enumerate(canvas.tasks, i):
            dep, previous = _analyze_canvas(t, previous, i)
            dependencies.extend(dep)
    elif isinstance(canvas, group) or isinstance(canvas, chord):
        new_previous = []
        for i, t in enumerate(canvas.tasks, i):
            dep, p = _analyze_canvas(t, previous, i)
            dependencies.extend(dep)
            new_previous.extend(p)

        if isinstance(canvas, chord):
            dep, p = _analyze_canvas(canvas.body, new_previous, i)
            return dependencies + dep, p
    else:
        t = canvas.name + " - (" + str(i) + ")"
        dependencies = [(t, previous)]
        previous = [t]

    return dependencies, previous
```